# ressources mapping in spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, mapping

can someone please help me with this issue. i'm new to spring so.. the problem is
in this case url = " localhost:8080/projectname/stuff" everything works fine ressources are imported but when i add "/" or any @pathVariable "/stuff/{id}" , ressources are no longer imported so i have no image no css nothing

spring-servlet.xml

```
     <import resource="data-config.xml"/>

     <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/" />

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
          <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:/META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bd"  annotation-config="true" /> 
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
   <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>
<bean id="handlerMapping"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
    <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>    
</bean> 

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
  <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/assets/**" security="none"/>


 <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous()"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin/question" authentication-failure-url="/login"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"
        />


        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="true"  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.bd.service.implement.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
<password-encoder hash="md5"/>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your resources this way :
Add `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` before `assets/`

example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/PATH_TO_YOUR_CSS_FILE/style.css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is flawed in multiple ways. You have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` that already configures a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. Next the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` is deprecated and replaced with `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and they currently compete with each other. The fix is simple remove both.

`<context:compont-scan />` already implies `<context:annotation-driven />` and already includes `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Hibernate doesn't need a load time weaver so you should be fine by removing that.

Removing all the clutter leaves you with the following.

```
<beans ...>

    <import resource="data-config.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd" /> 
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="language" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

i followed your advice about spring-servlet.xml 
the file now looks like this

```
 <import resource="data-config.xml"/>

     <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/" />

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

     <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:/META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties" />


     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistence" />

    </bean>

     <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bd"  annotation-config="true" /> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added :

> ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

before assets seems to solved the problem thanks –